# String contains (second instance of substring)

Tags: c#, string, substring, contains

I'm trying to manipulate a string using C#/razor.

What I want to do is show only the part of the string to the right of the second appearance of the word "Summary ".
So, for example, if the string is:

> Summary Symptoms Read More Summary A tarsal coalition is a bridge of bone that forms in the foot in late adolescence.  As the tarsal coalition progresses from a fibrous...

I want to display it as:

> A tarsal coalition is a bridge of bone that forms in the foot in late adolescence.  As the tarsal coalition progresses from a fibrous...

So, I guess what I need to know is how do you use "contains" to find the second instance of a substring within a string?

OK...so Soner has put me in the right direction, but when I try this, it errors:

```
@{

string s = @Html.Raw(item.ShortBody);

int firstindex = s.IndexOf("Summary ");
s = s.Remove(0, 8);
int secondindex = s.IndexOf("Summary ");

var strbody = s.Substring(secondindex + 8);
}

@strbody
```

How do I output the manipulated string to the screen on my view?   the @s isn't working..

Comment: You don't.  You use `String.IndexOf`

Comment: Contains will only tell you if the string contains the string you are looking for. So, you don't.

Comment: Regarding the error while trying to output your result - what kind of error is it (compile- or run-time) and what's the exact message of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no `Summary` word after your second `Summary`, you can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
string s = "Summary Symptoms Read More Summary A tarsal coalition is a bridge of bone that forms in the foot in late adolescence. As the tarsal coalition progresses from a fibrous...";
var array = s.Split(new string[] {"Summary "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Console.WriteLine(array[1]);
```

Output will be;

```
A tarsal coalition is a bridge of bone that forms in the foot in late adolescenc
e. As the tarsal coalition progresses from a fibrous...
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/ReNMvr)</kbd>.

If you have a Summary word after your second Summary, you can use [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`String.SubString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods like;

```
string s = "Summary Symptoms Read More Summary A tarsal coalition is a bridge of bone that forms in the foot in late adolescence. As the tarsal coalition progresses from a fibrous...";
int firstindex = s.IndexOf("Summary ");
s = s.Remove(firstindex, 8);
int secondindex = s.IndexOf("Summary ");
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(secondindex + 8));
```

Output will be;

```
A tarsal coalition is a bridge of bone that forms in the foot in late adolescenc
e. As the tarsal coalition progresses from a fibrous...
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/7ZUHvl)</kbd>.

Comment: what if another `Summary ` would be present after the second occurrence?

Comment: Hello and thank you for the rapid response! There will never be a third occurrance of the word Summary, so this should be fine I think.
I am wondering, though, how would I output the array value "inline" rather than to the console?  I ask, because this isn't working:
@{


string s = @Html.Raw(item.ShortBody);

var array = s.Split(new string[] {"Summary "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

}
@array[1]

Comment: @IlyaIvanov You can check now :)

Comment: If you are going to do it this way, you should use the version that takes a maximal count and limit the number of splits to 3: `Split(new [] { "Summary" }, 3, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: @SonerGönül  

I am getting an error when I try this as well...not sure how to output to screen??

@{

string s = @Html.Raw(item.ShortBody);

int firstindex = s.IndexOf("Summary ");
s = s.Remove(0, 8);
int secondindex = s.IndexOf("Summary ");

s = s.Substring(secondindex + 8);
}

@s

Comment: @embryo I think you really ought to be doing this transformation in the model, not the view.  If you must do it in the view, then construct it as normal in the code block and output it using the helper outside the code block.

Comment: I agree it should be in the model, but is not an option for me. I edited my original question to include the code I am currently trying to use. As you can see, I am calling the "s" variable outside of the code block, but it doesn't work....

Comment: One thing though...can somebody explain why we bother to set the "firstindex" variable?? It never gets referenced...

Comment: @SonerGönül

Can you please explain what the firstindex variable is for?

Comment: @embryo It is actually for `s = s.Remove(firstindex, 8);` line. I fixed it. `s.Remove` returns new string removing `8` character starting index `firstindex`

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the string always starts with the first summary, you can use the `IndexOf` signature that includes an offset before starting the search.

```
 var second = str.IndexOf("Summary", 7);
 var description = str.Substring(second + 8).TrimStart();
```

Alternatively, you could find the first, then use it's position to find the correct offset

```
 var second = str.IndexOf("Summary", str.IndexOf("Summary") + 7);
 var description = str.Substring(second + 8).TrimStart();
```

Obviously, these both rely on the fact that the string does contain at least two instances of the word `Summary`.  If that's not the case then you'll need to check that the results of `IndexOf` is equal to or greater than zero before attempting to find the substring.

Another alternative, if you know that there are at most 2 occurrences of the word is to use `LastIndexOf` instead of `IndexOf`, then take the substring after that.

```
 var second = str.LastIndexOf("Summary");
 var description = str.Substring(second + 8).TrimStart();
```

Comment: +1 second case is the most appealing. Also though about using `IndexOf` twice - this seems more robust and short, as to be compared to `Split` and `Join`